# Not able to fetch values from yaml file

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have a values.yaml file.

```
secret:
  Secret1: secret1
  Secret2: secret2
  Secret3: secret3
```

I have a deployment.yaml file where I am using helm templating and fetching the values from values.yaml file.

```
env: {{ range $key,$value := .Values.secret }}
            - name: "{{ $key }}"
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: {{ $value }}
                  key: {{ $value }}
              {{ end }}
```

This is giving me error when I run helm upgrade --install release-name chart-name command.Is there something wrong with my deployment.yaml file?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: You might start off running `helm template --debug chart-name`, and looking for this `env:` block in the output; does it look like the YAML indentation is correct?

Answer (score 0):

If the error something like:

```
error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line XX: did not find expected '-' indicator
```

Or:

```
error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line XX: mapping values are not allowed in this context
```

Might be an issue with your tabs/spaces

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: myapp
    env: {{ range $key,$value := .Values.secret }}
      - name: "{{ $key }}"
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: {{ $value }}
            key: {{ $value }}
    {{ end }}
```

Rendered this correctly for me:

```
spec:
  containers:

  - name: myapp
    env: 
      - name: "Secret1"
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: secret1
            key: secret1
    
      - name: "Secret2"
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: secret2
            key: secret2
    
      - name: "Secret3"
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: secret3
            key: secret3
```